# Aurelia-Router with child-router shows warning

Tags: javascript, promise, aurelia

I have the following code, basically a main router in app.js and a child router in dashboard js. Whenever I go to the root url '/' i get a warning in the browser console. I don't understand whats the problem here, the redirect even works correctly and everything displays, but I still get this giant warning telling me something went wrong. What am I missing? Any help appreciated.

browser console warning

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Object]
    at _buildNavigationPlan (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:14942:22)
    at BuildNavigationPlanStep.run (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:14922:14)
    at next (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:14488:20)
    at Pipeline.run (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:14501:14)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:16050:25
From previous event:
    at AppRouter._dequeueInstruction (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:16023:32)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:16014:17
From previous event:
    at AppRouter._queueInstruction (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:16011:14)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:15945:23
From previous event:
    at AppRouter.loadUrl (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:15944:53)
    at BrowserHistory._loadUrl (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11474:55)
    at BrowserHistory._checkUrl (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11467:14)
```

app.js

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;

    config.map([
      { route: '', redirect: 'dashboard' },
      { route: 'dashboard', name: 'dashboard', title: 'Dashboard', moduleId: 'views/dashboard', auth: true }
    ]);
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="material-design-lite/material.css"></require>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

dashboard.js

```
export class Dashboard {
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        this.router = router;

        config.map([
            { route: 'fairs', name: 'fairs', title: 'Messen', moduleId: 'views/fairs', nav: true },
            { route: '', redirect: 'fairs' }
        ]);
    }

    attached() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }
}
```

dashboard.html

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Comment: Could something be failing in your `dashboard.js` attached method, causing rippling errors?

Comment: Even without any attached methods I get the same error, it's definitly coming from the redirect, because only when I visit the / url the error shows up, if I visit the full url /dashboard/whatever, no error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking into the same thing, and I think it's written like that on purpose. The code causing the warning is from a long chain of promises that make up an AppRouter object.

Since a redirect step is handeled by a different method in that chain, when it gets to the [BuildNavigationPlanStep.run(...)](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/router/latest/class/BuildNavigationPlanStep/) step, that particular promise is rejected because it was handeled upstream ( [RedirectToRoute.navigate(...)](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/router/latest/class/RedirectToRoute) ). That's my best guess after reading through the stack trace.

I'm assuming that warning is being printed to console from the Bluebird promise api, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I have actually worked a fairly long time with this now and I came to the same conclusion as you did, there seem to be a few places where different things get rejected which are not "errors", that is what leads to these warnings but doesn't actually mean something is wrong, just an implementation default (the aurelia-fetch-client actually does the exact same thing with defaults). Guess we should just ignore them for now :) thank you